# Connection through the US, which airline's baggage rules apply?

Tags: usa, luggage, japan

The trip is:

Sao Paulo (GRU) -> Dallas(DFW) = American Airlines

Dallas(DFW) -> Tokyo (HND) = Japan airlines

Baggage rules and tariffs are very different on those. I already tried searching about it, but I get a multitude of answers.

It may be the MSC (Japan airlines), or the check-in carrier (American). Or the marketing carrier (either, depending on which one you buy from).

Thanks.

Comment: Is this under one ticket or do you self connect?

Comment: Usually: whoever you bought the ticket from. It's entirely possible to get different allowances on the same code shared flight, if you buy the ticket from another company.

Comment: @Willeke one ticket

Comment: https://www.iata.org/contentassets/e7a533819be440edbb1e49da96e0f2a8/guidance-document-on-baggage-standards-for-interline.pdf I believe the MSC’s allowance applies but have really just glanced at the doc.

Answer (score 4):

You have specifically asked about the fact you are connecting through the US.  As you're no doubt aware, the US has specific rules that vary from most other countries around how the charges for baggage should be applied.

This is covered in the US CFR (Code of Federal Regulations) as "[**14 CFR 399.87**](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-II/subchapter-F/part-399/subpart-G/section-399.87) **Baggage allowances and fees**" which states :

> For passengers whose ultimate ticketed origin or destination is a U.S.
> point, U.S. and foreign carriers must apply the baggage allowances and
> fees that apply at the beginning of a passenger's itinerary throughout
> his or her entire itinerary. In the case of code-share flights that
> form part of an itinerary whose ultimate ticketed origin or
> destination is a U.S. point, U.S. and foreign carriers must apply the
> baggage allowances and fees of the marketing carrier throughout the
> itinerary to the extent that they differ from those of any operating
> carrier.

As both of your flights have been purchased on a single ticket, your "ultimate ticketed origin [and] destination" are NOT US points, thus this regulation does not apply to your flight.

It is possible the check-in staff will still attempt to follow the US regulations, in which case if it's beneficial to you then you should allow them to, but if it's not then you should be free to raise this with them.